# Qt Android Building SSL Error

Tags: android, qt, ssl, https

I'm trying to build to android from qt.

**Qt version**: **5.11**

**OpenJDK** Version is: **10.0.1** *(openjdk-11-jdk)*

**Distro**: Ubuntu **18.04**

---

When I'm trying to build I got SSLException errors from everywhere. First it didn't download the gradle, I passed this by changing the gradle properties "**https**" address to "**http**".

But it continues and gives errors all the time. androidqtdeploy can't access https websites.

For example an error:

```
* What went wrong:
...
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.8/gradle-4.8.pom'.
            > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix this HTTPS and SSL issue and make my build continue and done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the HTTPS problems:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```